# Angular momentum in relativistic hydrodynamics

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics

When we study particle dynamics in General Relativity, the angular momentum is written as $$\mathscr{L}=-u_\phi$$
Whereas, the fluid angular momentum is expressed in terms of the 'enthalpy density' $h$ as $$\mathscr{L}=-hu_\phi=-\frac{p+\rho}{\rho_0}u_\phi$$

I could not understand why enthalpy is introduced in the expression for angular momentum for fluids.

Is it because mass conservation implies isentropic motion in the framework of GR, and thus the enthalpy term enters through the application of first law of thermodynamics to fluid flows?